# CSS from css file is directly inserted into html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When I check the page in developer tools, strangely the CSS code from CSS files has been inserted into the HTML and I don't know how. The project I'm working on uses angular js 1.

The link tag is written in the following format:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href=" " />
```

But in the developer tools, it is converted to:

```
<style media="" data-href="css/chartist.css">
 /* All the css code here */
</style>
```

Comment: well, that's not default angular behaviour. It's probably some vendor package that's responsible for that

Comment: can you make a fiddle where you reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @MihaiVilcu I don't know how that has happened. I don't think I can reproduce it.

Comment: Firstly, are you using any javascript packager's like webpack or browserfy.  Also are you sure it's in the page source, IOW:  Do you see this is `view page source` and not the Elements in the debugger.?

Comment: @Keith When I view page source, link tags are visible. Only in the developer tools its that way. Not using webpack or browserfy

Comment: Then it's either a library your loading into your page, or you have a browser extension that's grabbing external CSS and injecting into page.  To see if it's a browser extension just go to any other website and see if the css is injected the same way.

Comment: Other web pages are fine. Tried commenting all the javascripts then it was fine. Some script causing the issue.

Comment: Strange!, not sure why any script would want to inline an external css..  So just enable each one until you get the inlining again.  Also somebody on SO recently downloaded a template with some ad-aware scripts built in.    If it's the same with you, please let people on SO know, so we can name & shame.

Comment: Did that. A script called prefix free was causing that!

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  I would keep that one if you want to keep using standard css without the vendor prefixes in your css.  Or alternatively pre-process your css with something like SASS or LESS or autoprefixer.  If your also targeting modern browsers you may even be able to skip all together.

Comment: Um I actually don't know what a vendor prefix is. Can you explain what it is? I tried reading it online, but didn't understand very well.

Comment: this has popped up before: http://tagabukid.com/all-stylesheet-links-are-converted-to-data-href/

Comment: @hairmot Yes that exactly was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Extra Javascript called "Prefix free" was causing this behavior. After removing it, it started working fine.